# Custom keyboard shortcuts in Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell-ise

Can I configure custom keyboard shortcuts for the PowerShell ISE without adding them to the AddOnsMenu?

I'm referring to keyboard shortcuts such as 'Ctrl-M' (which expands/collapses outlining in the ISE Editor). I'm using PowerShell ISE Host 5.1.

The keyboard shortcuts I have in mind would do things like select and manipulate text in the editor based on caret position. Nothing as elaborate as PSReadline, just a few keyboard shortcuts to automate basic tasks.

I understand I can do this:

```
$Display = "Select Current Line"
$Action = { $psise.CurrentFile.Editor.SelectCaretLine() }
$Shortcut = "Ctrl+L"
$psise.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add($Display,$Action,$shortcut)
```

But I don't want to add anything to the AddOnsMenu. I'd prefer to have my shortcuts specific to my ISE $profile and/or session. Is this possible?

Comment: This is a good example of custom keyboard shortcuts: https://github.com/proxb/ISEMenuAddOns  The AddOnsMenu can serve as a reference, I suppose there's no reason not to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code posted can be added to the ISE profile. The collection of submenu items added to the AddOnsMenu are removed when you close the ISE.